# How to compress the output of MapReducer?

Tags: dictionary, compression, output, reduce

This is my new questions about MapReduce.

As we know Map/Reduce Output is stored in HDFS itself, so to save the disk space we can compress the final output and store it.

Do we have any inbuilt function or method to compress the O/P and store in HDFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are options for compressing the mapreduce output as well as the intermediate output.

Suppose you need to compress the final output in gzip format, you can mention the same in any of the following ways.

- While running the jar command

  ```
  hadoop jar <yourjar.jar> \
  -Dmapred.output.compress=true \
  -Dmapred.output.compression.type=BLOCK \
  -Dmapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec \
  -input <input-path> \
  -output $OUTPUT \
  ```
- From the Driver class

  ```
  FileOutputFormat.setOutputCompressorClass(job, org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec.class);
  ```
- By setting the configuration parameters

  MRv1

  ```
  conf.set("mapred.output.compress", "true");
  conf.set("mapred.output.compression.type", "BLOCK");
  conf.set("mapred.output.compression.codec","org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec");
  ```

  MRv2/YARN

  ```
  conf.set("mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress", "true");
  conf.set("mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.type", "BLOCK");
  conf.set("mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec","org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec");
  ```